# What is killing my Green Button Woods?

Tags: trees, tree-care

We have a pest guy who comes once a month to spray the property but it seems we cant get rid of these pests. I have caught a few of them in the attached pictures this evening. Some of the trees are ok, others are worse off then before. We purchased them as 3ft trees and the bulk of the 165 that we have are now 6-8ft. A few of them though seem.to have not grown at all so any help there too would be appreciated. Thanks in advance. [image][image][image][image][image]

Comment: You have quite a little zoo there.  I see two or three different insects in those pictures. Most of those pests look like a good spray of soap and water would put them away but I'll  let the fellow gardeners suggest an answer in detail.

Comment: Yes, I feel like the yard was not well taken care and because of thats its been a battle to get control of it. Just went out at night in case anyone is curious and didn't see much activity but we just had a very heavy wind and rain storm.